# Generate data frame from array for logistic regression

Tags: r

Say you have an array like

```
dat <-  array(c(126, 100, 35, 61, 908, 688, 497, 807, 913, 747, 336, 598, 235, 172, 58, 121,402, 308, 121, 215, 182, 156, 72, 98, 60, 99, 11, 43, 104, 89, 21, 36), dim = c(2, 2, 8),dimnames = list(a = c(1, 0), b = c(1, 0), c = 1:8))


> > dat
, , c = 1

   b
a     1  0
  1 126 35
  0 100 61

, , c = 2

   b
a     1   0
  1 908 497
  0 688 807

, , c = 3

   b
a     1   0
  1 913 336
  0 747 598

, , c = 4

   b
a     1   0
  1 235  58
  0 172 121

, , c = 5

   b
a     1   0
  1 402 121
  0 308 215

, , c = 6

   b
a     1  0
  1 182 72
  0 156 98

, , c = 7

   b
a    1  0
  1 60 11
  0 99 43

, , c = 8

   b
a     1  0
  1 104 21
  0  89 36
```

and you want to fit logistic regression to predict a. Is there a simple way to generate a data frame from this array to use in glm? ie a data frame like

```
a b c
1 1 1 for 126 rows then
...
0 1 1 for 100 rows, etc.
```

Basically I need to get data to fit logistic regression when given the table with counts. It seems like there should be a simple way of doing it without manually generating the data.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to start with the `melt` function in the `reshape2` package:

```
library(reshape2)

datM <- melt(dat)
head(datM, 2)
#   a b c value
# 1 1 1 1   126
# 2 0 1 1   100
```

Then `dcast` that data to get the numbers of outcomes on one row:

```
dat2 <- dcast(datM, b + c ~ a)
head(dat2, 2)
#   b c   0   1
# 1 0 1  61  35
# 2 0 2 807 497
```

You can then use this data to perform a `glm` where the response is a 2-column matrix giving the numbers of successes and failures:

```
response <- as.matrix(dat2[, c(4, 3)])
bb <- dat2[, "b"]
cc <- dat2[, "c"]
glm1 <- glm(response ~ bb + cc, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

---

However, the model degrees of freedom (and log-likelihood, etc.) will not reflect the data structure you asked for in your question. To get the specific data structure you were aiming for, you could go back to the `datM` object.

**EDIT:**

The following loops over all columns of `datM` except for the `value` column, repeating the values `datM$value` times:

```
datRep <- lapply(datM[-grep("value", names(datM))], rep, times = datM$value)
```

Then `cbind` that back into a `matrix` and convert to `data.frame` to get the data structure you wanted:

```
dat3 <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, datRep))

glm2 <- glm(a ~ b + c, data = dat3, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

The coefficients of the two models are the same:

```
> coef(glm1)
(Intercept)          bb          cc 
-0.43854838  0.77039283 -0.03328575 
> coef(glm2)
(Intercept)           b           c 
-0.43854838  0.77039283 -0.03328575
```

But, as mentioned, the degrees of freedom, etc will not be:

```
> glm1$deviance
[1] 29.39535
> glm2$deviance
[1] 11381.87
```

Comment: tyvm. exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Ugly as sin, but does what you need for this example.

```
dat1 <- data.frame(value = as.vector(dat),
    a=dimnames(dat)$a,
    b=rep(dimnames(dat)$b, each=length(dimnames(dat)$a)),
    c=rep(dimnames(dat)$c, each=length(dimnames(dat)$a)*length(dimnames(dat)$b)))
```

Better would be to use `melt`, as in @BenBarnes answer.  This is more flexible and avoids the creation of factors.

```
dat1 <- melt(dat)
```

Then to get the expanded rows, you can use `rep`

```
dat2 <- data.frame(a=rep(dat1$a, dat1$value),
                   b=rep(dat1$b, dat1$value),
                   c=rep(dat1$c, dat1$value))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative using base functions to get the counts data which you can then expand as in @MatthewLundberg's answer:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(do.call(expand.grid,dimnames(dat)),value=as.vector(dat))

   a b c value
1  1 1 1   126
2  0 1 1   100
3  1 0 1    35
4  0 0 1    61
5  1 1 2   908
...
```

Expand as stolen from previous answer...

```
dat2 <- data.frame(a=rep(dat1$a, dat1$value),
                   b=rep(dat1$b, dat1$value),
                   c=rep(dat1$c, dat1$value))
```

Answer (score 1):

A minimal way to undertake the first part, converting the array to the `data.frame` is to use `as.data.frame.table`. Then proceed as @MatthewLundberg or @thelatemail suggest.

```
df0 <- as.data.frame.table(dat)

head(df0)
#    a b c Freq
# 1  1 1 1  126
# 2  0 1 1  100
# 3  1 0 1   35
# 4  0 0 1   61
# 5  1 1 2  908
# 6  0 1 2  688
```